# How to upgrade AWS EC2 instance type t2.medium to t3.medium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I want to upgrade intance type T2.Medium to T3.Medium and follow the these steps.

- Stop the instance.
- Go to Instance Settings > Change Instance Type > t3.medium > Save.
- then try to start the Instance again.

But it's given me this type of error message -

```
**Failed to start the instance --instance-id--
Enhanced networking with the Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) is required for the 't3.medium' instance type. Ensure that your instance '--instance-id--' is enabled for ENA.**
```

```
**Failed to start the instance --instance-id--
Enhanced networking with the Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) is required for the 't3.medium' instance type. Ensure that your instance '--instance-id--' is enabled for ENA.**
```

How to fix this issue without losing any data?

Comment: You won't lose any data -- the contents of the disk is stored on an Amazon EBS volume that will keep your data independent of the instance type. This article seems to be relevant: [Enabling ENA support on your AWS EC2 - DEV Community](https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/enabling-ena-support-on-your-aws-ec2-2fcp)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you switched the instance type, it disabled ENA, probably because you can't manage ENA from the console. You'll need to use the 'aws' command to enable ENA on the instance via:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id <ID> --ena-support
```

Of course replace `<ID>` with your instance's ID.

If you don't have the aws command installed on any of your EC2 instances, it should be installed on the CloudShell that you can access from the console.